# Get list of taxonomies associated with Subscribers

Tags: custom-taxonomy, page-template, user-meta

I used [this tutorial](https://www.nopio.com/blog/add-user-taxonomy-wordpress/) so that I would have the ability to associate categories with users. However, I changed the code so that it would show only on Subscribers profiles (not Authors like in the tutorial).

What I would like to do now is create a custom page template which shows a list of Subscribers including their avatar, first name, last name, email address and all the categories associated with that user.

This is the code I have so far, but I don't know how to call the array of categories associated with each user:

```
// Create the WP_User_Query object
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query(array (
    'role' => 'Subscriber',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'display_name'
));

// Get the results
$subscribers = $wp_user_query->get_results();

// Looping subscribers
if (!empty($subscribers)) {
    foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber)
    {
        // get all the user's data
        $user_info = get_userdata($subscriber->ID); 

        //printing basic infos
        echo '<div style="width:290; float:left; margin-right:20px;">';
        echo '<div>';
        echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( $subscriber->ID ), 290 );
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div>';
        echo ''.$user_info->first_name.' '.$user_info->last_name.'';
        echo '</br><a href="mailto:'.$user_info->user_email.'">'.$user_info->user_email.'</a>';
        echo '</br>'.$user_info->description.'';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No Subscribers found';
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't sure how the categories were being associated with the users so I checked the tutorial you linked to and found this:

```
$user_meta = get_user_meta( $user_id, USER_CATEGORY_META_KEY, true );
```

It'd be whatever your code's version of that line is...  so whatever you're saving the categories as in terms of user_meta, you'd call that.  But change the *true* to *false* so you get all of them instead of just one.  From there you should be able to parse all of it however you want.